Convertir una imagen a base 64 en c#
Estoy trabajando con.net5 y estoy tratando de generar un doc pdf recibiendo una imagen en b64,en mi metodo para generar el pdf, recibo la informacion que va en mi pdf, y tambien recibo un string que es el b64 de mi imagen que va en mi pdf, dentro del metodo trato de convertir ese b64 en img para poder agregarlo en mi pdf, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:
System.IO.PathTooLongException: 'The path (mi base 64) is too long, or a component of the specified path is too long.'
public String GenerarPDF(InformacionModel cartaModel, String sB64)
{
String sB64CartaReceptora = String.Empty;
try
{
    // Convertir la cadena Base64 en una imagen JPEG
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sCartaReceptora);

    using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        // Crear un MemoryStream para almacenar el PDF
        using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Crear un writer de PDF
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfStream);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf, PageSize.LETTER);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.AddNewPage());
            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);

           //Se escribe PDF

           // Crear una imagen iText a partir de los datos JPEG
                     iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new             iText.Layout.Element.Image(iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(imageStream.ToArray()));
          // Agregar la imagen al documento
             document.Add(img);
             document.Close();

          // Convertir PDF a Base64
             byte[] pdfBytes = pdfStream.ToArray();
             sB64CartaReceptora = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);


         }
      } 
  }

}
Desconozco la cantidad de caracteres que son aceptados, pero mi base 64 es de aprox. 800,000 caracteres
Quiero sabes si es posible hacer lo que estoy tratando y si no, de que manera podría realizarlo.

Por qué en lugar de imageStream.ToArray() no pasas imageBytes directamente? Es como ir a comprar algo y volver con las manos vacías: pierdes el tiempo en vano.

Debes indicar la librería que estas usando junto con su versión
